# JQuery if statement can't get attr value

Tags: jquery, if-statement

This is working for me. But I'm not sure if .attr addes value

```
$(function() {
  $("input.upb").change(function (){
    var fileName = $(this).val();
    $(".added").html("Selected file(s) was added successfully").css("color","darkgreen").attr("id", "added");
  });
});
```

Is this statement misspelled?

```
$(function(){
  if($("input.upb").attr("id")=='added'){
    $("input.post").click(function (){
      $(".post").attr("value","Uploading ...");
      $(".progressbar").css("opacity", 1);
    });
  }
});
```

If statement not working :-(

Comment: For the first js code, you add id attribute on .added selector, then second js code you compare with another selector which is input.upb. Instead of using if($("input.upb").attr("id")=='added'), change to if($(".added").attr("id")=='added')

Comment: post your html code snippet as well.

Comment: what are you trying to do here

Comment: @ArunPJohny I need execute code if input.upb has id "added".
Without if statement code works

Comment: `<div class="input">
                        <div class="file"><input class="upb" type="file" name="files[]" accept="image/*" multiple required></div>
                        <div class="added">Files aren't added yet</div>
                    </div>`

Comment: @ApulGupta here is :-)

Comment: The input.udp selector you're checking against does not have the id attribute set at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the way you're checking the condition, control will never reach to the if statement, cos there is no event which invokes that statement, it should be inside the click of the "post" button, see working code below along with fiddle url-

You need to do this-

```
    $(function () {
    $("input.upb").change(function () {
        var fileName = $(this).val();
        $('input.upb').attr("id", "added");
        $(".added").html("Selected file(s) was added successfully").css("color", "darkgreen");
    });
    $("input.post").click(function () {
        if ($("input.upb").attr("id") == 'added') {
            $(".post").attr("value", "Uploading ...");
            $(".progressbar").css("opacity", 1);
            alert('inside if statement');
        }
    });
});
```

Then your if statement will work perfectly.

**Working Fiddle-**
**http://jsfiddle.net/hmxLf32s/14/**